# 2 Questions about Risc-V-Privileged-Spec-v1.7

Tags: riscv

1. Page 16, Table 3.1:
   Base field in mcpuid: RV32I RV32E RV64I RV128I

   - What is "RV32E"?
   - Is there a "E" extension?
2. ECALL (page 30) says nothing about the behavior of the pc.
   While mepc (page 28) and mbadaddr (page 29) claim that "mepc will point to the beginning of the instruction". I think ECALL should set the mepc to the end of the causing instruction so that a ERET would go to the next instruction. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by CliffordVienna, RV32E ("embedded") is a new base ISA which uses 16 registers and makes some of the counter registers optional.

I would *not* recommend implementing a RV32E core, as it is probably an unnecessary over-optimization in core size that limits your ability to use a large body of RV*I code. But if performance is not needed, and you *really* need the core to be a tad smaller, and the core is not connected to a memory hierarchy that would dominate the area/power anyways, and you were willing to deal with the tool-chain headaches... then maybe an RV32E core is appropriate.

ECALL is treated like an exception, and will redirect the PC to the appropriate trap handler based on the current privilege level. MEPC will be set to the current PC of the ecall instruction.

You can verify this behavior by analyzing the Berkeley RV64G Rocket processor (https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket/blob/master/src/main/scala/csr.scala), or by looking at the Spike ISA simulator (starting here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/master/riscv/insns/scall.h). **Careful:** as of 2015 Jun 27 the code is still in flux regarding the Privileged Spec.

If we look at how Spike handles eret ("sret": https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/master/riscv/insns/sret.h) for example, we have to be a bit careful. The PC is set to "mepc", but it's the trap handler's job to advance the PC by 4. We can see that done, for example, by the proxy kernel in some of the handler functions here (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk/blob/master/pk/handlers.c).

Answer (score 1):

A draft of the RV32E (embedded) spec can be found here (via [isa-dev mailing list](https://lists.riscv.org/lists/arc/isa-dev/2015-06/msg00022.html)):

https://lists.riscv.org/lists/arc/isa-dev/2015-06/msg00022/rv32e.pdf

It's RV32I with 16 instead of 32 registers and without the counter instructions.